# Approximations of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function, special-functions, approximation, bessel-functions

We know that
$$f(x)={\rm e}^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{(n!)\color{red}{^1}}\tag{1}.$$
We can approximate $f(x)$ by the function $$g(x)=b^x\,\,{\rm with}\,\, b\approx {\rm e}.\tag{2}$$
By letting  $b$ become closer to ${\rm e}$ we can adjust the goodness of the approximation and in the limit
$$\lim_{b\to {\rm e}}g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{(n!)\color{red}{^1}} \tag{3}$$
the approximation coincides with the infinite sum.
We slightly modify the infinite sum in eq.$(1)$ and get
$${\rm I}_0\left(2\sqrt{x}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{(n!)\color{red}{^2}}\tag{4},$$
where ${\rm I}_0$ is the modified Bessel function of first kind and zeroth order. Is it possible to approximate eq.$(4)$  in the way as $g(x)$ approximates $f(x)$? There we have the property, that the less the constants $b$ and ${\rm e}$ differ, the better is the approximation for the infinite sum.
As eq.$(1)$ and eq.$(4)$ differ only by $n!$ I am motivated to find for eq.$(4)$ an approximative function $h$ with the structure $$h(x,c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_k)\approx{\rm I}_0\left(2\sqrt{x}\right),\tag{5}$$ where $c_i$ are a finite set of constants. Analogous to eq.$(3)$ the approximation shall become exact in the limit
$$\lim_{c_i\to d_i \forall i} h(x,c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_k)={\rm I}_0\left(2\sqrt{x}\right),\tag{6}$$
where $d_i$ are unknown (transcendental) constants.

*What I tried:*

For $x=1$ we get the constant ${\rm e}$ from eq.$(1)$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(n!)\color{red}{^1}}={\rm e}\approx 2.71828\tag{7}$$
and analogous we get another less known constant from eq.$(4)$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(n!)\color{red}{^2}}={\rm I}_0(2)\approx 2.27959\tag{8}.$$

Now one could use an approximate value of ${\rm I}_0(2)$ (together with some other constants) to get an approximation for ${\rm I}_0(2\sqrt{x})$ without using infinite sums.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134049/discussion-on-question-by-granular-bastard-approximation-of-sum-n0-infty-f).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quoting from Wikipedia:** In mathematics, an *elementary function* is a function of a single variable (typically real or complex) that is defined as taking sums, products, and compositions of *finitely many* polynomial, rational, trigonometric, hyperbolic, and exponential functions, including possibly their inverse functions (e.g., $\arcsin$, $\log$, or $x^{1/n}$).

As you can see, the exponential function is on the list. Now, the modified Bessel function $I_{0}$ is a *non-elementary function*. You can express it in terms of elementary functions but such an expression will always involve an *infinite process*, e.g., infinite series, integration, etc. It may be hard to accept that adding an extra factorial to the sum changes things so dramatically, but that is the case here. You have to accept that what you are asking for is not possible, not because mathematicians are incompetent but because of the nature of mathematics.

It was shown by Hankel that
$$
I_0 (2\sqrt x ) \sim\frac{{\mathrm{e}^{2\sqrt x } }}{{2\sqrt{\pi} x^{1/4} }}\left( {1 + \frac{1}{{16\sqrt x }} + \frac{9}{{512x}} +  \cdots } \right),
$$
as $x\to +\infty$. This is a divergent [asymptotic expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion) in the sense of Poincaré. For the full expansion, see [$(10.40.1)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.40.E1) in the NIST DLMF. The series is divergent for all $x>0$ but any truncated version of it yields a good approximation for $I_0$ for large positive values of $x$. This asymptotics also shows you how the function deviates from $\mathrm{e}^x$.

When $x<0$, your sum can be written in terms of the $J_0$ Bessel function as $J_0 (2\sqrt { - x} )$. The behaviour for large negative $x$ is given by [another result](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.17.E3) of Hankel and it shows an oscillatory behaviour. At leading order
$$
J_0 (2\sqrt { - x} ) \approx \frac{1}{{\sqrt \pi  ( - x)^{1/4} }}\cos \left( {2\sqrt { - x}  - \frac{\pi }{4}} \right),
$$
when $x$ is large and negative.

The above two asymptotics shows that the behaviour of your series is rather different when $x>0$ or $x<0$ and may also convince you that it is not possible to capture two such different behaviours by a single approximation.

Comment: @kevinkayaks Sorry about that, comment removed. I wrote the best answer I could. I cannot see how to convince the OP that what he/she asks for is impossible.

Comment: @granularbastard You say in your question that the approximation should become exact in the limit. You don't want infinite processes in the formula for $h$. This would mean that the exact from with the $d_i$'s would be an elementary function according to the definition in the Wikipedia. And that means that $I_0$ is also an elementary function according to the definition in the Wikipedia. But we know that $I_0$ is not an elementary function. So we have a contradiction. Therefore having such an appoximation is impossible. What is your take on that?

Comment: I understand your point. One should focus on the closure property of elementary functions. "It follows directly from the definition that the set of elementary functions is closed under arithmetic operations and composition." (from same Wikipedia article). Is it proved that we know all possible arithmetic operations?

Comment: @granularbastard By arithmetic operations they mean addition, subtraction, multiplication and division.

Comment: Can you prove that we cannot define other operations? My question has more a philosophical background. Of course I know that $I_0$ is not an elementary function in the common sense. But how do we know that this is the last word? You write that what I am looking for is impossible. But which sense of impossible do you mean? Impossible by current knowledge or impossible at all? Why should mathematics abruptly change if we go from $\sum \frac{1}{n!}$ to $\sum \frac{1}{n!^2}$?

Comment: You can define other operations. The question is, what you allow in your function $h$? I am stating that it is not possible to express $I_0$ as an elementary function of a finite number of variables. Of course if you consider $b^x$, $b>1$ say, it contains infinite processes when $x$ is not a whole number. How would you compute $3^\sqrt{2}$ in a finite number of steps? Perhaps you can post your general (philosophical?) question as a separate question on this site or even on MathOverflow.